# Как решить аффинное уравнение (шифрование)?

Tags: криптография

Есть буквы с кодом `1` и `27`. По формуле шифрования получаю:
При дальнейшем изучении текста получаем, что с большой вероятностью за ними скрываются буквы с номерами 4 и 19 (0,1...27).

```
E(x) = (a*4 + b) mod 28;
E(x) = (a*19 + b) mod 28;
```

Это зашифрованные буквы. Я пишу систему уравнения:

```
1 = (a*4 + b) mod 28
27 = (a*19 + b) mod 28;
```

Вычитаю из второго первое и получаю `26 = 15*a mod 28`. Как отсюда найти a?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Уравнение  `x mod y= z` - оно же `x % y = z` имеет множество решений относительно `x`, в частности:

```
x = k*y + z //где k любое целое число
```

В вашем случае:

```
15а=28k+26 //где k любое целое число, а предполагается тоже целое
```

Путем несложного перебора находим, что:

```
k=13, a=26 //15*26 = 28*13+26 = 390
```

Comment: Неплохой вариант. Я уже и забыл про этот вопрос, но я чуть по-другому сделал. В итоге без перебора получилось